# TypeError: Member "gas" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple(bool,bytes memory)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, javascript

> How do I fix this?

```
abstract contract AionClient is Aion, Context, Ownable{
using SafeMath for uint256;
using Address for address;
address private AionAddress;
constructor(address addraion) public{
    AionAddress = addraion;
}





function execfunct(address to, uint256 value,uint256 gaslimit,bytes memory gas, bytes memory 
data) internal virtual returns (bool) {
    require(msg.sender == AionAddress);
    return to.call{value:value}("").gas(gaslimit)(data);
}


receive () external payable {}

}
```

Comment: I get a message like this. What should I do?　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　TypeError: Return argument type function (bytes memory) payable returns (bool,bytes memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) bool. return to.call{value:value}{gas:("(gaslimit)(data)")}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatting is just off with the call. The [Solidity Documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#value-types) details this as the way to do this:

```
address(nameReg).call{gas: 1000000}(abi.encodeWithSignature("register(string)", "MyName"));
```

So you should change your code to be:

```
return to.call{value:value, gas:gaslimit}(data);
```

Comment: return to.call{value:value}{gas:("(gaslimit)(data)")}; Solidity 6.5

Comment: I tried, but I could not do it in "Solidity" 6.5.

Comment: What I tried in the comment above is return to.call{value:value}{gas:("(gaslimit)(data)")};"